# Alternative for Report.Load() event in Ms Access 2003

Tags: ms-access, events

I created an application in Access 2003 and continued to work on it on another computer with Access 2007. I created a report with a method that loads data from a recordset to some unbound fields on the report. This method takes three parameter values from three fields on the report. The report's data source is a query.

I call the method in the report's Load() event, like `LoadSummary([field1],[field2],[field3])` and works fine in Access 2007.

I switched back to Access 2003 and the Load event is unavailable. I've tried calling the method using the Open, Page and Activate events but all fail because it seems like when these events fire, the fields have not been populated with the data yet.

Please help. How can I get this to work in Access 2003? Any eye openers are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the OnFormat event of the report header section.   If that doesn't work try the detail sections OnFormat event but but in a report level boolean variable so it only does it once.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I had to call the method from both the header and detail section format event.