# Form information passed to Report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm currently working on an Access Database that was developed by a previous employee and have been introduced to maintain/tweak the system as needed. The system stores the information of a task done by an employee and has various reports that can be created to view the metrics. In order to make these reports more clear to those reading them, I want to add the "Date Viewed" to the Report Header.

In order to open the reports, the manager clicks a From button (either for today, yesterday, or a specific day) which loads the corresponding report. For both "Today" and "Yesterday", I am able to put the date in using =Date() and =Date()-1. However, I am having trouble doing a similar thing for the Specific Date.

My solution so far has been through the button press on the form, InputBox gets the day, month, and year from the manager to generate the report from that day in the WHERE statement. I would like to use these values (dt, mo, yr) in the Report, but am not sure what to put in the Report to pull these values from the vba code. Ideas to this, or a different way to approach it, would be appreciated!

Current vba code is below. From what I've read, there are techniques to make a temporary query/table/form to store the info, then pull it back in the report. Or there are ways to make those variables "Public" and be pulled from various locations, but that method is currently over my head.

```
Private Sub SpecificSummary_Click()

Dim stDocName As String
Dim yr As Integer
Dim mo As Integer
Dim dt As Integer

mo = InputBox("Enter Month:")
dt = InputBox("Enter Day:")
yr = InputBox("Enter Year:")

stDocName = "SpecificSummary"
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , "((Year([TimeStamp])) = " & yr & ") And ((Month([TimeStamp])) = " & mo & ") And ((Day([TimeStamp])) = " & dt & ")"

End Sub
```

More Info in RE: to HansUp

For the Today and Yesterday Reports, in the Report Header using a Textbox, I use =Date() for the Today, and =Date()-1 for Yesterday.

Update: As requested, here is the current code/method for the Today Report.

```
Private Sub TodaySummary_Click()

Dim today As Date
Dim stDocName As String
Dim yr As Integer
Dim mo As Integer
Dim dt As Integer

today = Date

yr = Year(today)
mo = Month(today)
dt = Day(today)

stDocName = "DailySummary"
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , "((Year([TimeStamp])) = " & yr & ") And ((Month([TimeStamp])) = " & mo & ") And ((Day([TimeStamp])) = " & dt & ")"

End Sub
```

In the Report (TodaySummary), I use...

```
=Date()
```

to print out the date

I feel like I am making this much harder than it should be, and am blindly missing an obvious method for using dates instead of breaking it into Year/Month/Day and using the WHERE condition that way.

Comment: One of the posts I was trying to help guide me was this one, it seemed a bit confusing using the OpenArgs part.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398804/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-into-an-access-report-programatically

Comment: @HansUp Updated in the Question. Using those in the report header in a textbox with the Control Source as =Date(). And yes, there are three separate reports at the moment.

Comment: The other design difference would be in the vba coding, instead of the Inputbox today and yesterday use the code below to satisfy the WHERE condition. 

today = Date

yr = Year(today)
mo = Month(today)
dt = Day(today)

Comment: The VBA code is under the module for the form, under the sub for the button click that will load the report. The code is the same as shown in the question, just the inputbox part is changed between today/yesterday/specific date, if that makes sense.

Comment: I'll keep working on it for a while longer, researching and testing. If I'm not able to find a solution by tomorrow I'll work on zipping and upload it for people to take a look at. Thank you for the time HansUp!

Comment: You just need topost your code for the Today and Yesterday code - it should be exactly the same for specific date - just use a textbox marked as a date format - they can click on the date to pick it - supply the date to the report in the same way you do the other WHERE clauses - show us that and we can show some code for you

Comment: @dbmitch I've added the code to the original question. I'm guessing my issue is that I'm not supplying the report with a date based on the WHERE clause, but instead am directly evaluating the date with =Date() when the report opens.

Comment: That helps. I assumed you were just using one report - that would be much easier. But this makes more sense now when I look at your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now - I assumed you were using the same report for all queries - which is certainly possible.

But if all you want to do is to dynamically change a text field in the Report Header - you can certainly do that.

In your report,   **EDIT USE REPORT_LOAD event**
open the Report_Load event
then edit the event to look like:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Dim strTextDate As String
    strTextDate = Nz(Me.Report.OpenArgs, "")

    ' Replace "Text5" with your control
    Text5.Value = strTextDate
End Sub
```

Change your code to:

```
Dim stDocName As String
Dim yr As Integer
Dim mo As Integer
Dim dt As Integer

Dim strTextDate As String

mo = InputBox("Enter Month:")
dt = InputBox("Enter Day:")
yr = InputBox("Enter Year:")

' Change this to match your date format
strTextDate = "" & yr & "-" & mo & "-" & dt

stDocName = "SpecificSummary"

' Add date to last OpenArgs parameter of OpenReport
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , , acWindowNormal, strTextDate
```

**Make sure to close and save your Report Design before running code**

Comment: Working on it right now, running into error "2448: You can't assign a value to this object" and it highlights the Text5.Value = strTextDate line.  Running line by line strTextDate gets the string, but isn't letting it be put into the Text5 box.  Just to be sure, the Text5 is the name of the textbox I want the date to be entered in, in the report?

Comment: It has to be the control that YOU use on your report - mine was just an example

Comment: Edited - Can't use Report_Open - controls not accesible yet - use Report_Load

Comment: Yep, I understand that. In the report design, the Textbox is named Text22, and so in the code I am using Text22 instead of Text5. Do I need to change the Control Source of the textbox as well? And if so, does that go to something like =[strTextDate] or =[Text22] or =[OpenArgs]?

Comment: Got it! Nothing in Control Source needed, name as Text22, and used this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041397/alternative-for-report-load-event-in-ms-access-2003 : to adapt the on load to on format, as the software is in 2003.  Thank you @dbmitch for your help!